# Application of Hoeffding's inequality to the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, machine-learning

I'm following this [note](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Erebeschi/teaching/AFoL/20/material/lecture15.pdf) to learn about deriving an upper bound of the UCB algorithm on the Stochastic Multi-Armed Bandit Problem. In particular, the proof of Lemma 15.6 there connotes that we can apply Hoeffding's inequality to
$$ Pr\left(\frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} - \mu_a \geq \epsilon \right) $$
where $Z_{s,a}$ are iid with mean $\mu_a$ and are independent of other rewards, $A_s$ is the action we make at time $s$ which is in general a function of the past rewards and past actions, $N_{t,a}=\sum_{s=1}^t I_{A_s=a}$.

Of course, a natural starting point is to condition on $N_{t,a}=n$, so that inside the probability there are $n$ iid random variables. However, I cannot proceed because $Z$'s are clearly not independent of $N_{t,a}$ (as $N_{t,a}$ depends on $(A_s)_{s=1,...,t}$ and each $A_s$ depends on $(Z_{i,a})_{i=1,...,s-1, a\in A}$; in particular, UCB speficies $A_{s+1}= argmax_a U_{s,a}:= \frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} + \sqrt{\frac{log(s)}{2N_{s,a}}}$).

Similarly, online notes [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6783/2021fa/lec25.pdf) (page 2, Lemma 1) and [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse599i/18wi/resources/lecture3/lecture3.pdf) (page 8, Theorem 4) all directly claim that we can apply Hoeffding's inequality to the above inequality without justification.

I'm aware that there are other methods to derive an upper bound for UCB, but I'd really like to confirm if this approach is a dead end.

Comment: Why are $Z$'s not independent of $N_{t,a}$?

Comment: @sudeep5221 Basically because $N_{t,a}$ depends on $(A_s)_{s=1,...,t}$ and each $A_s$ depends on $(Z_{i,a})_{i=1,...,s-1, a\in A}$; in particular, UCB speficies $A_{s+1}= argmax_a U_{s,a}:= \frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} + \sqrt{\frac{log(s)}{2N_{s,a}}}$. 

At least more justification is needed to show $Z$'s are independent of $N_{t,a}$, but I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a simple counterexample to the approach of conditioning on $N$. Consider the UCB algorithm for $k=2$ (the action space has two elements only). According to the algorithm, at $t=1$, we choose $A_1=1$ and sample $Z_{t=1,a=1}$; and at $t=2$, we choose $A_2=2$ and sample $Z_{t=2,a=2}$. $\tag*{}$

Then $t=3$ gives the counterexample: we set $A_3=\text{argmax}_a \{U_{t=2,a=1}, U_{t=2,a=2}\}$, which is equivalent to choosing $A_3=1$ if $Z_{1,1}>Z_{2,2}$ and $A_3=2$ otherwise, then we sample $Z_{3,A_3}$. Consider the following

$$
P( \frac{1}{2} (Z_{t=1,a=1} + Z_{t=3,a=1}) - \mu_1 \geq \epsilon | N_{3,1}=2)
= P( \frac{1}{2} (Z_{1,1} + Z_{3,1}) - \mu_1 \geq \epsilon | Z_{1,1}>Z_{2,2})
$$

This shows $Z$’s and $N_{t,a}$ cannot be independent in general; furthermore, conditioning on $N$ may alter $Z$'s distribution, e.g. making $Z$'s no longer have the same mean.

Hence, I believe this is an error in the notes. To still work out an overall bound for the risk, we need to consider other approaches altogether. e.g.

https://tor-lattimore.com/downloads/book/book.pdf (page 104, theorem 7.1)

https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/37364663/ZHAO-SENIORTHESIS-2020.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y (page 22, theorem 2.7)

---

Thanks to @JohnPrice's pointer, it's possible to show that
$$ Pr\left(\frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} - \mu_a \geq \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)k}{2N_{t,a}^2}} \right) \leq \delta^{\frac{k}{t}}, \forall k $$
(this answer is adapted from [Lemma 6.2](https://rltheorybook.github.io/rltheorybook_AJKS.pdf)).

*Proof*: Define $X_i:=(Z_{i,a}-\mu_a)\mathbb{I}_{A_{i}=a}$. Define $\mathcal{F}_{<i}$ to be the natural filtration formed by all actions $A_j$ performed before time $i$. We claim that $\forall i, E[X_i|\mathcal{F}_{<i}]=0$. To see this, notice that the UCB algorithm for choosing the next arm to pull is deterministic when conditioned on all actions in the past; if the next arm is $a$, then the indicator equals $1$ and $E[Z_{i,a}-\mu_a]=0$ ($Z_{i,a}$ is independent of the past), if not, the indicator equals $0$.

Hence, $\{X_i\}$ is a martingale difference sequence and by Azuma-Hoeffding ([general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azuma%27s_inequality)),
$$Pr\left( \sum_{i=1}^t X_i \geq \epsilon:=\sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)k}{2}} \right)\leq \exp\left( - \frac{2\epsilon^2}{t} \right) = \delta^{\frac{k}{t}}$$
(where we used $\sum_{i=1}^t X_i^2 \leq t$ in Azuma-Hoeffding). Then, observe that $\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^t X_i \geq \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)k}{2}} \right\} = \left\{ \frac{1}{N_{t,a}}\sum_{s=1}^t Z_{s,a} I_{A_s=a} - \mu_a \geq \sqrt{\frac{\log(1/\delta)k}{2N_{t,a}^2}} \right\}$

**PS**: The proof in [Lemma 6.2](https://rltheorybook.github.io/rltheorybook_AJKS.pdf) claimed that it used Azuma-Hoeffding but there is one key step where it bounds $\sum_{i=1}^t X_i^2$ by $N_{t,a}$ and uses $N_{t,a}$ (which is random) in Azuma-Hoeffding, which is unjustified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, $\{Z_{s,a}\}_{s=1}^t$ are not independent given $N_{t,a}$. So we need the concept of Martingale and use the Azuma-Hoeffding inequality.

In fact, in the original paper, the authors indeed used it. See Fact 1 in *Finite-time Analysis of the Multiarmed Bandit Problem* by Peter Auer et al. Although the inequality is somehow named "Chernoff-Hoeffding bounds".

Comment: I don't think Azma-Hoeffding helps in this case because $N$ is a random variable itself (which depends on the past rewards) and when we condition on $N$, the rewards may no longer have the required mean. So I think the notes made a mistake (see a simple counter-example in the accepted answer). 

The original paper used another approach so Azuma-Hoeffding is applicable there.

Comment: @NXWang I don't understand why the rewards no longer have the required mean. By definition, for a fixed arm $a$, its reward mean is $\mu_a$ regardless of the history. So $\{Z_{s,a}-\mu_a\}_{s=1}^t$ is a martingale difference sequence and we can apply Azuma-Hoeffding.

Comment: The definition only says $Z_{s,a}$ by itself are iid for different $s$ and has mean $\mu_a$, but when you condition the sum of rewards on $N$ (or even more, condition on all past rewards), it will alter the distribution. For example, as shown in the accepted answer, $\frac{1}{2} (Z_{1,a}+Z_{3,a})$ given $Z_{1,a} > Z_{2,b}$ no longer satisfies martingale difference since $Z_{1,a}$ given $Z_{1,a} > Z_{2,b}$ may not have mean $\mu_a$ whereas $Z_{3,a}$ given $Z_{1,a} > Z_{2,b}$ and $Z_{1,a}$ still has mean $\mu_a$ (by independence).

Comment: @NXWang Thanks, this is indeed subtle. However, I still think with some effort we can still use Azuma-Hoeffding. Here is an [example](https://rltheorybook.github.io/rltheorybook_AJKS.pdf) (Page 64, Lemma 6.2).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I modified the accepted answer accordingly (adapting from your link). (I still doubt the key step where it just replaces the deterministic bound in Azuma-Hoeffding with a random quantity $N$, so my proof is a bit different)